# can I save CSS values in my Wordpress theme without a MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, css, database, wordpress

I am a little bit of a newbie at Wordpress theme development, and I can't find the answer here or through much Google foo, so I wanted to find out if this scenario is possible.

I'm writing a child theme for Themetatic and I wanted to provide end users with the ability to change CSS color values and font family from a dialoge box in the theme controls.  Does this require storing their entries in the database or can I just store these directly in the CSS file?

Comment: I think that CSS will be better option.

Answer (score 1):

No, you will need to create a theme_option that WP will store in the database and an interface for the user to edit these options.

There is a great tutorial on how to do all of this [here](http://blog.themeforest.net/wordpress/create-an-options-page-for-your-wordpress-theme/).

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need to store them in the database. you can do something like this:

html:

```
<a id="style1" href="?view=black"></a>
<a id="style2" class="current" href="yourwebsite.com"></a>
```

and put the following in the header.php

```
if(isset($_GET['view'])) {

 <link href="style1.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

} else {

<link href="style2.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

}
```

Comment: In this case the user has to create a CSS file, they may as well just edit the current one and not bother with this conditional.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would go about doing this would be by creating a Dynamic CSS file after the color/font values have been changed. Your CSS file would then be re-created to include these changed values.