# Right way for pass variable php to css in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

i need to passing variable from php to css for customize style from custom theme option.

The only way i have find is create file.css.php
and working good.

But my question is: This is good for website load a file .css.php ? or can have some other problem, like speed or seo?

There are some other good methods?
Thx

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/

Comment: You might want to look into just using an inline style within your PHP template. Maybe something like `style="<?php echo $css-thing; ?>"` or what ever you are trying to do.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245596/can-i-save-css-values-in-my-wordpress-theme-without-a-mysql-table

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Indirect solution:

It sounds like you want to include different CSS behavior based on user selection. Let's say that user selection is stored in a variable `$foo`. Just include it in an element's class like this

```
<?php 
$foo = 'option-1'; ?>
<div class="<?php echo $foo; ?>"></div>
```

---

## There are also two *direct* solutions to your issue:

#### 1. Use inline CSS or CSS in your file's page head:

```
<style>
  div.button { color:<?php echo $bar ?>; }
</style>
```

#### 2. Use a PHP file as CSS. This would look like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.php">
```

Then you can use PHP variables right inside your CSS file. Just make sure you change the `content-type` back to CSS at the beginning of the file like this:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8"); ?>
```

This method is a little bit unconventional, but it'll work without any speed or SEO drawbacks.