# use css style on php file wordpress variable access

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

hi guzz i am create wordpress plugin and i want to access php variable on css style i include `'style.php'` file and i want to access php style variable on this file but how ,
my php code

```
<?php 

   function my_style_render(){
        // mystyle file load
        wp_enqueue_style('mystyle', MY_PLUGIN_URL."/css/my_style.css");

        $color = '#149382';
        ob_start();
        include MY_PLUGIN_PATH . '/css/style.php';
        $custom_css = ob_get_clean();
        wp_add_inline_style( 'mystyle', $custom_css );

    }

?>

//and my style.php file

.model_inline {
    background-color: {$color};
}
```

but color in not apply on **'model_inline'** class ...
anyone suggestion ..

Comment: i want access data of color that store in database and i want to store in $color variable and use database stored color so i can use style,php file i accecc inline css on this file

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43689560/right-way-for-pass-variable-php-to-css-in-wordpress

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code.

For eg:

In HTML:
You can call css file like this.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.php" />
```

in style you can add this code.
Style.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/css');
$var = /*Get the background color*/;
?> 
.wrap{
    background-color:<?php echo $var; ?>;
}
```

Comment: Some more great examples of implementation: https://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/